# How to make polygon from buffered point collection in postgis

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to make polygon of an airport which must be given distance from start point and end point of runway given as latitude and longitude.
[image: airport polygon]

Query I've made looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO airport (name, polygon) 
VALUES(
      'some airport name', 
      ST_SetSRID(
        ST_Collect(
            ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(160.04518, -9.43196), 100), 
            ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(160.06376, -9.42452), 100)
        ), 4326
      )
);
```

unfortunately result polygon is very weird, it covers almost all earth. I've also tried to add srid to each point but it also didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872887/4270929
before adding buffer to point it must be cast to geography (in geometry is in different unit I guess?)

```
ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(160.04518, -9.43196)::geography, 100)::geometry, 
ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(160.06376, -9.42452)::geography, 100)::geometry
```

Comment: You specified coordinate system 4326, so the unit was in degrees